# How to enforce the use of the base keyword

Tags: c#, resharper, fxcop, radix, stylecop

we are using `ReSharper`, `FxCop` and `StyleCop` on our projects and I'm trying to find a way to enforce the usage of `base.` instead of `this.`

Do you know if it is possible with the mentioned tools? All I found is related with forcing the usage of `this` (which we already use).

Regards.

Comment: You could write your own StyleCop rule and hang it in ReSharper (through hanging StyleCop in ReSharper). This will allow you to use the same mechanism (Code Inspection) as ReSharper, but for your own rule. Change its' settings at Inspection Severity.

Comment: Are you trying to force use of `base` whenever it _could_ be used instead of `this`, or are you trying to detect cases where it looks like `base` probably _should_ have been used instead of `this` (e.g.: inside a method override to call the base method)?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: hello Nicole, I'm trying to do the first thing to include it in the company coding standard. Thanks

Comment: Why exactly?  Are you aware that the compiler will essentially substitute `base` for `this` in the generated IL for cases where this does not make a difference?  This, btw, tells you that you can't use FxCop for the rule, so it would need to be StyleCop and/or R#.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: it is more a readability thing. If you see a base you know that the method comes from the base implementation, if you see a this you know that the implementation is on the file you are currently looking at.

Comment: That's quite brittle.  The day someone adds an override for a pre-existing method, all the `base` calls in that class' file will potentially become incorrect, both functionally and wrt your convention.  If you want to make it easier to find method implementations, you might want to consider using something like the Productivity Power Tools to facilitate navigation, rather than potentially impacting your code's maintainability via a rule like this.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: that's a good point. I'll think about it, thanks!